# How to use ng-options and ng-init in AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, json, twitter-bootstrap

I have object like in this below format. How to display all the ProjectID's in drop-down list and user can select any one value? Please give me one example.

```
[
  {
    "ProjectManagerID": 4,
    "ProjectID": 4,
    "ResourceID": 4,
    "Deleted": false
  },
  {
    "ProjectManagerID": 5,
    "ProjectID": 8,
    "ResourceID": 5,
    "Deleted": false
  },
  {
    "ProjectManagerID": 6,
    "ProjectID": 9,
    "ResourceID": 6,
    "Deleted": false
  },
```

Comment: Actually, I am getting this response from service. So, i have to bind the data from service.

Comment: try this `ng-options="item.ProjectID as item.ProjectID for item in items"`

Comment: @SSH why `item.ProjectID as`?

Answer (score 1):

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("myController", ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.options = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Value to show user"
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "some other value"
      }];

      $scope.optionValue = '';
    }
  ])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <select ng-model="optionValue" ng-options="opt.id as opt.name for opt in options">
      <option value="">Please select a value</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Bootstrap dropdown menu

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">ProjectManagerID</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ProjectID</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ResourceID</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-repeat` as well

```
<select ng-model="selected"
        class="form-control">
    <option value={{project.ProjectID}} ng-repeat="project  in YOUR_PROJECT_LIST">
        {{project.ProjectID}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: If I use selecterpicker then its not working.  I am using selecterpicker class. So that I can select from drop down list and user can search.

Comment: @user2677311 I've used it with `ui-select` and `ui-select-choices` too. Had to give the vm variables instead of `$scope`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl" ng-init="ctrl.setProject(8)">
    <select ng-options="project.ProjectID as project.ProjectID for project in ctrl.projects" ng-model="ctrl.projectID">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

angular
    .module('demo', [])
    .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);

function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.projects = 'Your data goes here!';
    vm.setProject = setProject;

    function setProject(projectID) {
      vm.projectID = projectID;
    }
}
```

[check this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uc8znva8/) ng-options is used to generate the `<option>` tags for `<select>` it should be used along with the ng-model directive, as shown in the above e.g. with jsfiddle working e.g.

The reason why the as clause is used here in the ng-options is that we are setting the selected `<option>` using projectID and writing it in that fashion will set the selected `<option>` based on the property specified in the as clause.

The ng-init directive is used to do any initialization for an appropriate controller scoped to that particular DOM area, to show it in action in the given example we are setting the selected option using a function called in the ng-init directive, but it is more appropriate to do this directly in the controller rather than using the ng-init directive

Try to read this [style guide from John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) it is amazing.